# Node.js: Differing buffer output

Tags: node.js, base64, decode

i have decoded a base64-encoded string using buffers, now i have noticed something *funny*:

this works fine, outputs the decoded string as utf8

```
decoded = new Buffer(data.content, 'base64')
console.log('Decoded:' + decoded);
// outputs content of a markdown file
```

however, this outputs hex characters:

```
decoded = new Buffer(data.content, 'base64')
console.log(decoded);
// outputs<Buffer 23 20 33 30 32 34 20 66 ...>
```

why is this or what am i doing wrong? shouldn't the output be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of `console.log` is formatted internally in node.js using `util.format`. (See line 52 of https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.4/lib/console.js)

When you call `console.log(obj);`, `obj` is passed directly to `util.format` internally. When you call `console.log('Decoded: '+obj)`, the string concatenation forces `.toString()` to be called on `obj` first, and then passes the resulting combined string to `util.format` internally.

So, in the first case, node.js is formatting a `String` object, in the second case, it's formatting a `Buffer` object directly.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Mozilla Javascript Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString):

> Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when
>   the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is
>   referred to in a manner in which a string is expected.

Node.js buffer docs: [Buffer#toString](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end).